# What the difference between the 'urban' and 'city-living' tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tags

Is there a difference between these two tags?
Should they be merged?

Comment: Looks like a synonym target to me indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Neither one has a summary that would suggest a real difference. I believe they should be merged.

Answer (score 0):

Two separate tags with their own meaning might be urban-detached-living and apartment-living. There are enormous differences in what activities you can do depending on whether or not you have a back yard.